# Set up Tensorflow GPU on Jupyter notebook, windows 11

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu, windows-11

For the past two days, I've been trying to set my GPU up to use with Jupyter notebook. I've gone through several tutorials, but nothing seems to work for me, or at least, I don't understand what steps I need to take.

When I attempt to install cudnn, I encounter the following message:
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.6.0.163.`

I tried to install TensorFlow 2.10, but I still get the same error message.

Could anyone please help me?

I have python 3.8.8

Here is my nvidia set up

| NVIDIA-SMI 536.40   Driver Version: 536.40       CUDA Version: 12.2  |

Comment: Looking at [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu), seems like you might want to downgrade your CUDA installation to 11.2.

Answer (score 0):

The error stats that you are not using correct version of CUDA and cuDNN compatible to Tensorflow 2.10 for GPU support which are `CUDA 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.1` as mentioned in this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).

As you are using Windows OS, you need to install `Tensorflow 2.10` or earlier version to have GPU support enabled in your system because

> GPU support on native-Windows is only available for `2.10` or earlier
> versions, starting in `TF 2.11`, CUDA build is not supported for
> Windows.

Please refer to the [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) page and follow all the **step by step instructions** by checking the Hardware, Software requirements mentioned for GPU support.